# No puedo hacer peticiones a mi backend en Angular. POST - 404 (Not found). Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angular, post, http, cors, access-control-allow-origen

Estoy teniendo un problema para hacer peticiones a mi propio back.
No puedo correrlos en el mismo puerto.

Mi back corre en el puerto 3000 y mi front corre en el puerto 8080.
Quiero hacer una peticion HTTP POST. El servicio trata de pasar un email, lo busca en una base de datos, lo codifica y me lo envia.

Tengo un en la raíz del proyecto un `proxy.conf.json` con la siguiente información.

```
{
    "/api/*":{
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Y a su vez, corro el servidor con un `npm start` configurado de la siguiente manera en el `package.json`:

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    ...
}
```

Con eso. Al correr el servidor, dejó de aparecerme el error de CORS. Pero cuando se realiza la petición me aparece el siguiente error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/login 404 (Not Found)
```

Y tambien:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:8080/login', ok: false, …}
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /login</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/login: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:8080/login"
```

Mi peticion en Angular está hecha de la siguiente manera (los datos están hardcodeados por una cuestion de probar):

**Antes en la url tenía: "http://localhost:3000/login" pero lo cambie al hacer el proxy**

```
async getToken(email:string){
    return await this.http.post<any>("/login", '{username: "miqueasdavidgentile@gmail.com"}'); 
    //We deliver the token
  }
```

En postman la peticion si funciona:

[image: Postman funcionando la peticion]

Comment: No se si eso tenga que ver, pero en la función `getToken` en los datos hardcodeados que mandas en el cuerpo de la petición, no es un json válido. Agrégale las comillas a `username`. Me haces saber si así funciona.

Comment: Jeje, entre tanto tocar lo habré cambiado. Me sigue apareciendo el error. No era eso.

Comment: Otra cosas, ¿por qué envías un string y no un objeto normal? ¿Probaste sin comillas? Ahh ya vi tu error. En el postman estás haciendo la petición al puerto 3000, pero nota en el mensaje de error que adjuntas que en tu aplicación estás haciendo la petición al 8080.

Comment: Si, probé sin comillas y tampoco me funcionó.
Si, eso veo que en el mensaje aparece en el puerto 8080, no sé si es porque no detecta que está el proxy o me falta hacer alguna configuración mas.

Comment: Prueba harcodeando la `url` en el  `this.http.post` a `http://localhost:3000/login`

Comment: También lo intenté :(. Con eso a parte de salirme los dos errores que aparecen en la publicación, también me aparece el error de:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135416/discussion-between-miqueas-gentile-and-jaime-menendez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era que el `proxy.conf.json` estaba mal declarado.
El contenido del archivo era:

```
"/api/*":{
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
}
```

Pero la url NO contiene /api/*
La de login no es como tal "http://localhost:3000/api/login"

Por lo tanto lo cambié a lo siguiente y funcionó:

```
{
"/login":{
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
}
}
```